# No module named conda.cli

Tags: python, conda

Other questions here have suggested that my PATH variable is set wrong, but I checked my ~/.bashrc and found this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:   /usr/local/games"
export PATH="/home/name/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

When I run "python" from terminal, I get

```
 Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Mar 27 2018, 17:29:31) 
 [GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
```

Which looks like Anaconda's installed properly.

However, I can't run any commands starting with "conda" - I just get a

```
ImportError: No module named conda.cli
```

Comment: Looks like you are exporting the path to anaconda3, while when running python you have python2.7 running instead. Can you check to see if changing your path to "/home/name/anaconda2/bin" works?

Comment: Didn't work, I now get    Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2 when I type "python", but get conda: command not found

Comment: Hmm interesting, on my linux machine running `which python` or `which python3` will show me the installation locations of python. Very odd that it has returned to using the python 2.7.12.

Comment: Typing "python3" as a command gets me "Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
"! "which python" gets me "/usr/bin/python" and "which python3" gets me "usr/bin/python3". Is that useful info?

Answer (score -3):

In your PATH variable, it is pointing to "

> /home/name/anaconda3/bin/

Instead, it should point to

> /home/name/anaconda3/scripts/

where there should be a `conda.exe` file. This should solve your problem.

Also, looks like you're using Python 2.7, but the path is configured for python 3. Try using Python 3 instead.

Run the command `where python` , this will give you the installation directory of python. Set the directory to the path variable (make sure that you add this path BEFORE the python 2.7 directory in the `PATH` variable).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Replacing bin with scripts gets me the message "conda: command not found", and where python gets me this message: "No command 'where' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gwhere' from package 'gwhere' (universe)
where: command not found
"

Comment: This may be correct on Windows, but the OP Is clearly not on Windows, since they are setting the PATH in a .bashrc file and the path specified looks like it is from some *nix variant.